# How to keep the timezone when converting POSIXct to character?

Tags: r, posixct

```r
> t <- as.POSIXct("2019-04-03 03:00:32", tz = "CET")
> ct <- as.character(t)
> ct
[1] "2019-04-03 03:00:32"
> t
[1] "2019-04-03 03:00:32 CEST"
```

The goal is to have `ct` being exactly `"2019-04-03 03:00:32 CEST"`.

Comment: `format(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")`

Answer (score 1):

We may use `strftime` with `usetz = TRUE`

```
strftime(t, '%F %T', usetz = TRUE)
```

Comment: Also `as.character(t, usetz = TRUE)`